# Spring MVC how to convert string into json array using ajax

Tags: java, spring

If I write my Ajax code like this,

```
$('#calendar').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            
            var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YY-MM-DD');
            var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YY-MM-DD');
            
            var dates = { "startDate": startDate, "endDate": endDate };
                        
            $.ajax({
                url: "selectCouponByTerm",
                type : "post",
                data : JSON.stringify(dates),
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success : function(data){
                    var jData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log("커스텀 날짜 데이터 : " + jData);
                    dataTable.attr('data', jData).trigger("create");
                },
                error : function(e){
                    console.log(e.status);
                }
            })
        });
```

The result I got back is String like the picure below.

[image]

However, I want returned data to be like this.[image]

So I edited `var jData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`.
Then the picture below is the result I got back. [image]

How can I get returned data as json array?

Comment: Aren't you already getting the data as a JSON array. What happens if you remove all the JSON operation on the `data` field?

Comment: Then I got `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'startDate': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'startDate': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')` error. Chrome console shows 404 error.

Comment: That is coming from your spring app and must be happening regardless of how you parse the response json.